# how to make beep function sound better

Tags: c++, audio, beep, morse-code

I'm trying to make a morse code program that you can use to convert words to morse code. I'm using the Beep function, but the space in-between each beep is either too long, or changes from beep to beep. I tried using the sleep function, but it didn't work. Is there any way to make the beeps faster or more consistent?

Here's a sample for the letter S

```
int main() {

  Beep(400,500);
  Beep(400,500);
  Beep(400,500);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Beep` is a really stupid function suitable only for beeping. If you want something smart, you'll have to pull in an audio library. Not sure why the `Sleep` function couldn't give you the spacing you wanted, though. You should add the experiment with `Sleep` to the question; it might only need a small tweak.

Comment: Assuming you're coding for windows and the version of windows (you haven't specified), `Beep()` depends on hardware on your machine.  Originally, `Beep()` assumed specific hardware that is rarely on modern machines - from windows 7 it uses the default sound device.   Either way, quality of the sound depends on hardware.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [`PlaySound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/using-playsound-to-loop-sounds) instead. Just create a very small WAV file with a sound which can be looped without glitches and use `PlaySound("MY_SOUND.WAV", NULL, SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);` to start playing it. `Sleep(long_or_short_playing_time);` for as long as you want it played and then turn it off with `PlaySound(NULL, NULL, 0);` and then `Sleep(time_between_beeps);` - Repeat for the next beep etc.

Comment: I'd recommend using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono:: milliseconds(ms_between_beeps))` from `<thread>` and `<chrono>` to implement a delay.